# Make thread uninterruptable mac os

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel, lldb

I'm developing multi-threading application on mac os. I'm faced with next problem: when i'm trying to debug with xcode-cocoa application(NOTE: console application doesn't have same problem), my threads are returning with errors in next calls: kevent(), semaphore_wait(), semaphore_timedwait() with EINTR (for kevent) and KERN_ABORTED (for semaphore_*). I think this is due to lldb work.

The problem is: i can't debug my application as i'm crashing after receiving such events. If i will do their handling(just make recall of same function) then my application is working very strange. Anyway I can't(I can, but it's very ugly) make good handling for such situation when my semaphore_timedwait() interrupting as i should "remember" time before i have gone timedwait() to make new timedwait() correct.

So, solution for my problems would be if I could disable for current thread "interrupting" - ability to be interrupted from another thread\process, that my functions will not return if lldb will send some signal. Is it possible on mac os?

Answer (score 0):

Few notes:

1. In some debugegrs (I know gdb supports that) you can say whether all threads or only the one are stopped on the breakpoint.
2. Generally, you should be ready in your code a signal comes even if it is more work.
3. In multithreading application you can consider blocking the signals in most (helper) threads, so the signals shall be handled in a thread which is ready for that. See `pthread_sigmask()`.